# How to set a property of all entities in a Google Datastore to the same value using php-gds?

Tags: php, entity, google-cloud-datastore

I am using **php-gds** to connect and work with my **Google Datastore** via **PHP**. All my users are stored in there and they all have a property called 'points' containing an integer. I want to set this property of **all users** to 0 every month. I already have a cron-task starting the function that shall do this at the right time, but I am not sure how to implement the actual reset. This is what I thought of:

```
$store = new \GDS\Store($GLOBALS['userSchema']);
    $store->query('SELECT * FROM User');
    while ($arr_page = $store->fetchPage(50)) {
        foreach($arr_page as $user){
            $user->points = 0;
            $store->upsert($user);
        }
    }
```

Is this the right way or will this fail since I am **upserting while fetching**? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My example runs without any problems for several weeks now.